# Replace a generator of an ideal in the polynomial ring over the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

$ f$ and $g$ generate an ideal I $\subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ show that we can replace the generators with two new generators such that one of them has zero constant term.

I know $f,g-hf$ also generate the ideal where h is any element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I also know if it exists the remaining constant term must be the gcd of the original constant terms and I know the gcd can be written as a linear combination of these original terms.

Lets call the constant terms F and G. Then zF+wG=gcd(F,G). Maybe I can use this to write my new generators somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to the constant terms. If you apply the same operations that the algorithm applies to the constant terms to the polynomials, you're applying your rule $(f,g)\to(f,g-hf)$ in each step, and you end up with a constant term zero since the Euclidean algorithm ends up with zero.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\ $ Let $\rm\:0 \le f_0 \le g_0\:$ be the constant terms of generators $\rm\:(f,g) = I\:$ with $\rm\:f_0+g_0\:$ minimal. Then necessarily $\rm\:f_0 = 0\:,\:$ for otherwise $\rm\ (f, g-f\:) = I\:$ produces a smaller pair of constant terms. Note that this is essentially Euclidean descent on the constant terms.